# Узнать скопирован ли файл. Если да, обработать его

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Допустим, кто-то копирует файлы на сервер в место "B" из вне каким-нибудь файл-менеджером.

Как понять, является ли файл в месте "B" полностью скопированным и если да начать его обрабатывать?

Comment: Ну это вам рыть в сторону FileSystemWatcher. И если он вдруг не дает нужной информации о том, что изменение файла закончилось, то придется пытаться открывать файл до победного. Пока его копировальщик не отпустит винда все равно не даст к нему доступа.

Answer (score 0):

Код рабочий, проверял, скачивая через wget образ Debian OS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BusyFileObserver
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool isBusyFile(FileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            FileStream stream = null;
            try
            {
                stream = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.Close();
            }
            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathToFile = @"C:\Users\isnullxbh\Downloads\debian-distro.iso";

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToFile);
            while (isBusyFile(fileInfo))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nisBusy...");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToFile);
        }
    }
}
```